# MySQL in docker-compose -- access denied

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, localhost

I try to start `MySQL` server with `docker-compose`. Here is `docker-compose.yaml` part:

```
  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
    - /Users/user/Documents/.docker/mysql/config:/etc/mysql/
    - /Users/user/Documents/.docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='123'
    - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='172.18.0.1'
```

You see I've specified root password and host as it is said [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#mysql_root_host). Then I try to connect to db (using Intellij Idea if that matters):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=123&ssl=false
```

But it doesn't accept the credentials and writes to log:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Please advise on how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Give your user permission to connect from localhost.

Comment: Do you mean root user can not connect from localhost?

Comment: Yeah, the root user currently only has permission to connect @`172.18.0.1` and not from localhost as far as I can see

Comment: I don't need an ability to connect from localhost since all my applications will run on host machine. Does mysql demand having access from localhost in any case?

Comment: Your connection string is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=123&ssl=false` see the `localhost` ? That's a problem.

Comment: This connection string is used on host-machine and not on docker container. I could remove `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` at all and the issue will stay the same. Afaik docker proxies connection from host-machine to localhost as connection from remote address (`172.18.0.1`) to server on virtual machine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely you have initialized the mysql data directory when these were different:

```
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='123'
- MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='172.18.0.1'
```

MySQL image only honors those vars when the /var/lib/mysql directory is created.

So if you don't care about the data, empty your volume: `/Users/user/Documents/.docker/mysql/data`, or change the credentials manually from mysql terminal.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, those were not initial settings. Clearing the persistence directory helped.

Comment: I tried to change the password from mysql terminal, but still had to clear the persistence directory, otherwise root host wasn't being set by environment variable

Comment: What do you do if you do care about the data? Why is the design this way? What should I do if I want to change the MYSQL username used to create the container?

Answer (score 0):

if not in production you can also use the below with docker run
-e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
Also it will be better to create your own docker network

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it doesn't work for me. When I connect through the container and list the users, root does have an entry for "%" too. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

In my case

```
dataSource.setCatalog(...)
```

helped.